# Show Data from dataframe from a pandas frame in pyqtgraph modul window (set via qt designer widget)

Tags: python, pandas, pyqtgraph

I hope this isn't a stupid question. I have a main program where I import 2 modules. Once a module which I start to connect to an ESP (via BLE) and receive data via Notify. This data is then saved in the module in an Excel file.

```
async def handle_uuid2_notify(self, sender, data):

        ir_values = numpy.frombuffer(data, dtype=numpy.uint32)
        for ir_value in ir_values:
            if ir_value:
                ir_list.append(ir_value)  

        if len(spo2_list) == 100 and len(ir_list) == 100:
            global df, first_run
            new_data_available = True

            if first_run:
                df = pd.DataFrame({'Red': spo2_list, 'IR': ir_list})
                df.to_excel(filename, index=False)
            elif new_data_available:
                new_data = pd.DataFrame({'Red': spo2_list, 'IR': ir_list})
                df = pd.concat([df, new_data], ignore_index=True)
                df.to_excel(filename, index=False)

                global first_run_file
                global Dateiname
                if first_run_file:
                    print(filename)
                    Dateiname = filename
                    first_run_file = False

            spo2_list.clear()  
            ir_list.clear()
```

This function is started in its own thread via multithread. This thread is then started in the main script by clicking on a button. Then I import the generated filename into my main script and print the data in a table (this works):

```
def updatethetable():
    print("starte update")
    from safe_to_excel import Dateiname

    Datei_pandas = pd.read_excel(Dateiname, engine='openpyxl')

    model = QStandardItemModel()
    model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(Datei_pandas.columns)
    table_view = rohdaten_window_ui.RohdatenTableView
    table_view.setModel(model)

    # F?ge die Datenzeilen hinzu
    for row in range(Datei_pandas.shape[0]):
        data_row = [QStandardItem(str(item)) for item in Datei_pandas.iloc[row]]
        model.appendRow(data_row)
       # Verkn?pfe den TableView mit dem Frame in der UI
        table_view = rohdaten_window_ui.RohdatenTableView
        table_view.setModel(model)
```

But now I want to plot the respective data. First I would like to plot the last data of the data frame or the Excel file, initially only the 100 values at a time. After that I would like to display the 100 values one by one and when the 100 values of the array has been output, load new 100 values.

To plot the values, I first created another module and imported pyqtgraph. Also a .ui that I created with qt designer and in the qt designer I created a widget which I promoted. Here my module:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
import pandas as pd

uiclass, baseclass = pg.Qt.loadUiType("plotter_window.ui")

class PlotterWindow(QMainWindow, uiclass):
    def __init__(self, df):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.plot(df)

    def plot(self, df):
        spo2_list = pd.Series(df['Red'][:100]).astype(float)
        self.graphWidget.plot(spo2_list.values)

def open_plotter_window(df):
    window = PlotterWindow(df)
    return window
```

I call this module in the main script and can now create my plotter window. But how do I get the data plotted now? Either the pandas frame (pf) or the last 100 values of the table.